# Trigger 'select' event on jQuery UI Autocomplete when browsing results with arrow keys

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

What is the easiest way to trigger `select` event on jQuery UI Autocomplete search field when browsing results with arrow keys up and down? After that user can clear the field by pressing backspace only once.

[image]

You can test your approach with [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/haba713/kq5u4t68/) copied from [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: To clarify, when the User selects an option, you want the field to populate with the selection and then the text to become highlighted so the User can delete the content with a single keystroke. Would just creating a callback for Backspace keystroke to delete entire field be enough?

Comment: That’s a good workaround but highlighting the value would make it more predictable for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get to a point where you're competing with jQueryUI for focus, but you can get around this by setting a timeout, so your focus takes place on the next js cycle after jQueryUI is done.

You can use AutoComplete's focus event:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags, 
  focus: optionFocused
});
```

And then build a function that selects and focuses the text on the next cycle

```
function optionFocused(event, ui) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#tags').select().focus();
  }, 0)
}
```

Here's a working snippet

```js
function optionFocused(event, ui) {
 setTimeout(function(){
    $ ('#tags').select().focus();
  }, 0)
}  

$(document).ready(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags, 
      focus: optionFocused
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a note from this Demo: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

You can do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7m9qs3wc/5/

**JavaScript**

```
function quickDel(tObj) {
  tObj.val("");
}

$("#tags").on("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE &&
    !$(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
    event.preventDefault();
    quickDel($(this));
  }
}).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

This will quickly delete all the content of the field when Backspace is the Menu is NOT active.

If you want to highlight it, you can write a highlight function to be used in `focus` and trigger it in `Select` callback.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7m9qs3wc/12/

Note, `focus` in Autocomplete is in regards to the Menu items. So we call `.on("focus")` for the field itself.

Or do it all when you have Focus on a menu item: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7m9qs3wc/19/

Comment: The first approach does not seem to work reliably. See [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HSZr_v6KY9bHClmGTkDx1MYlkeitJwWV/view).